# How can I add rotation attributes to an Icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to rotate an image based on the heading/direction of my device, This class produces the `MarkerIcon` widget

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class MarkerOption {
  final MarkerIcon? defaultMarker;
  final MarkerIcon? advancedPickerMarker;

  MarkerOption({
    this.defaultMarker,
    this.advancedPickerMarker,
  });
  MarkerOption copyWith({
    MarkerIcon? defaultMarker,
    MarkerIcon? advancedPickerMarker,
  }) {
    return MarkerOption(
        defaultMarker: defaultMarker ?? this.defaultMarker,
        advancedPickerMarker:
            advancedPickerMarker ?? this.advancedPickerMarker);
  }
}

class MarkerIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon? icon;
  final AssetImage? image;

  MarkerIcon({
    this.icon,
    this.image,
    Key? key,
  })  : assert(icon != null || image != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget? child = SizedBox.shrink();
    if (icon != null) {
      child = icon;
    } else if (image != null)
      child = Image(
        image: image!,
      );
    return child!;
  }
}
```

I am using the Location Plugin that allows you to add the rotation attributes to the widget like this
`MarkerIcon( rotation: currentLocation.heading )`This way the image will point to which ever direction my device is pointing.But I don't know how to use it in this class. How can I add these attributes to the class such that I can call it like this?

```
 markerIcon: MarkerIcon(
             image: AssetImage(
              "images/images/arrow.png",
              rotation: position.heading,
            ),
          )
```

Comment: you can use `Transform` to handle this, how much you want rotate? can you share an image of that page

Comment: Hi Yeasin, The rotation is dynamic, say if my device is pointing to the east then the image will point to the east if west then west.  This is why I am using the `Location` plugin to get the heading of my device and hence want to rotate it as per the orientation of my device..

Comment: well, you may can calculate and assign that . im havenot done ityet